# Asterisk Transfer call to next extension if previous INUSE

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, voip, pbx

I am trying to transfer call to next extension if previous is using (INUSE) or call is in progress. I tried to use `EXTENSION_STATE(extension[@context])` to find the status as follow:

```
[sales]
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/123)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${EXTENSION_STATE(123)}"="INUSE"]?passed:failed)
exten => s,n(passed),Dial(SIP/124)
exten => s,n(failed),Hangup();if other
```

But wasn't successful. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me using GROUP_COUNT() instead of EXTENSION_STATE:

```
exten => s,1,Set(GROUP()=OUTBOUND_GROUP)
exten => s,2,GotoIf($[ ${GROUP_COUNT()} > 1 ]?try1:try2)
exten => s,3(try1),Dial(SIP/124)
exten => s,4(try2),Dial(SIP/123)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is way compilcated, it's basically one of the reasons it's not working. You should rather try this, this is a common simplier approach using internal variable `${DIALSTATUS}`. Since when answered - the call will be simply hung up, you just need to handle all of the erroneius statuses:

`[sales]
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/123)
exten => s,2,Goto(${EXTEN}-${DIALSTATUS},1)
exten => s-BUSY,1,Dial(SIP/other)
exten => s-CONGESTION,1,Dial(SIP/someone)`